# Returned Date as a string timestamp (Unix?) not sure

Tags: objective-c, timestamp

I'm working with some videogame server data.  The server returns a dictionary with past game details.  One of the fields is for the date.  That returned object is a string like this:

/Date(1286749014000-0700)/

I'm not exactly sure how that string translates into the date, but it should represent Sunday, October 10, 2010, 3:16 PM.

Is this a Unix timestamp? Do they usually have a suffix like -0700?

Thank you

Comment: apparently it is a unix timestamp, but I'm not sure what the suffix is for.  On it's own, it returns the year 42745.  On a guess I divided the number by 1000 and came up with the correct date.  please reply with something helpful for a free answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number `1286749014` stands for 10 october 2010 5:16:54 pm. So if you substract the 700 from it you should get the right date and time.

Check out the Wikipedia article on [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for more information on how it's made up.

Comment: Am I subtracting 700 from the first part of the timestamp?

Comment: You must subtract it from the current timestamp, for clarification on how timestamps work, use this site http://www.epochconverter.com/ on that site you can also give as input an human readable value.

Answer (score 0):

The first part ("128674901") exactly represents "Sun, 10 Oct 2010 22:16:54 GMT" date.

In objective-c you can use something like this:

```
NSTimeInterval unixDate = 128674901;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a high resolution time with timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

The "0700" suffix is a time zone.
Which means UTC -07